# Oracle SQL select last row in the table based on 1column

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

From the data table i need each person last loan date and bank name.

Please see attached image with input and expecting output.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use Oracle's `keep` syntax:

```
select name, max(loan_date),
       max(bank) keep (dense_rank first order by loan_date desc) as bank
from t
group by name;
```

This syntax is Oracle's fancy way of implementing a "first" aggregation function.